# evisions Argos - vertical name:value output widget?

Tags: report

When reading 20+ columns horizontally, it gets hard on the eyes. I've been trying to find a way to display output of a single search result row as a scrollable vertical columnName:columnValue list:

```
+-------------------------+-+
| First_Name | John       | |
| Last_Name  | Doe        | |
| Birthdate  | 01011970   | |
| Last_login | 01012015   |X|
+-------------------------+-+
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is functionality you can push to the database.  For example if your DB is oracle 11g, you can use the unpivot feature.

Create a multicolumn list box with the below query.

```
select column_name,column_values from customers
unpivot
(column_values for column_name in ("FIRST_NAME" ,"LAST_NAME"))
```